# Ultra deep water maximum pipe length

Tags: surface-tension, stress-strain

In the oil extraction industry an ultra-deep water drilling ship is a platform with a long pipe in its bottom connected to an oil field up to 12,000 feet below sea level.

Such pipe descend slowly from the platform.

being an steel pipe, in the worst case scenario you will have 11,999 feet of steel pipes hanging from the first pipe (connected to the drilling platform), at the last moment of the descent.

so, how long can a continuos and uniform steel pipe be, before it couldn't be any longer (due to the ultimate tensile strength rupturing the pipe start by its own weight)?

Comment: please show your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: @sammygerbil I haven't, it's just a mind exercise. I haven't done physics since college years ago :)

so instead of relearn the whole thing, I just thought about asking for some approximations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the pipe has constant cross section, then the stress at the top of the pipe will be the weight of the pipe minus the weight of the displaced water, divided by the area.

This means that for a pipe of length $\ell$, the stress is

$$\sigma = \ell(\rho_s-\rho_w)g$$

Density of steel = 8050 kg/m$^3$

Density of seawater = 1029 kg/m$^3$

So for a length of 12,000 feet = 3658 m, the stress is 250 MPa

The tensile strength of steel is about 250 MPa - so you are going to have to be very careful how you hold the pipe (any jaws holding the pipe will locally increase the stress). Perhaps you want to fill the pipe with air (or even just with sweet water) to provide a degree of buoyancy that reduces the stress on the pipe.